# How do I group numerical data into groups from a dataframe to make a bar chart with matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I have a dataframe only containing peoples ages and a want to make a bar chart with matplotlib. In order to do this i want to organize the data from the age column into groups like 0-4, 5-9 etc. How do I go about making a bar chart by putting the ages into groups?

Comment: Could you share some of the data in your dataframe? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly assign each age group a numerical value, make it a new column in your dataframe, and then use this to plot a seaborn `countplot`. I am using `countplot` instead of barplot because I assume that you want to plot the counts of each group on the graph, and for this countplot is the most efficient method. If not then let me know.

---

1. Creating random data (Run the code below to work on the exact same data as me) -

```
np.random.seed(42)
ages = [np.random.randint(0, 80) for _ in range(10000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(ages, columns = ["Age"])
```

2. Making age groups -

```
age_groups = [range(age, age + 5) for age in range(0, 80, 5)]
```

3. Assigning each age a group -

```
age_group = []

for age in ages:
  for i, group in enumerate(age_groups):
    if age in group:
      age_group.append(i)
      break
```

4. Making it a new column in the dataframe -

```
df["Age Group"] = age_group
```

5. Plotting a seaborn `countplot` -

```
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize = (20,5))
sns.countplot(x = "Age Group", data = df)
plt.show()
```

Output -

[image]